# How to suppress or convert characters such as smart quotes in an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, character-encoding

Given and text input and a textarea, is it possible to convert characters such as smart quotes to normal quotes?

Is it possible to do this using HTML tags (perhaps `pre` or `meta`)?

Is it possible to suppress them?

What is a good way of doing this in the browser, before submitting the form?

This is for an English language page that needs only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

how about `<form accept-charset="character_set">`